# How to configure DBT sources from Big Query EXTERNAL_QUERY

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

In Big Query, I am using an external connection/federated SQL query (cloudSQL) from which I can get data with `SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("gcp-name.europe-west3.friendly_name", "SELECT * FROM database_name.external_table;")`

Now my question is, in DBT, how do I define this source in my schema.yml file and how should my `FROM {{source(...,...)}}` statement look like?

Comment: Hi @andreas030241, when you say "External Source" are you are referring to BigTable or CloudSQL? From what I've seen in [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources), those are the only sources supported but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: Also maybe open an issue on [dbt-external-tables/issues](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables/issues) to describe the new source? I *think* this would need a new "loader" to handle for a sql external source instead of just a file lake style external source.

Comment: Hi @sgoley I'm referring to a CloudSQL table

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective right now given my above comments on the current state of the `dbt-external-tables` package (which I don't believe meets your needs), I would say you have two options:

1. Define your external dependencies as static views in a custom schema and then import as dbt sources.
2. Define your external dependencies *within* dbt using something like `Evaluate(<select *>)` and then `ref()` those like normal in your transform / stage layer.

---

Example of #1

```
* my-bq-project-id
  |
  |_ dbt_schema
  | 
  |_ external_db_schema
    |
    |_ external_table_1
    |_ external_table_2
```

etc.
And then you'd have:

```
* my-dbt-project-dir
  |
  |_ analysis
  |_ data
  |_ models
  |  |_ sources
  |  | |
  |  | |> my_external_table_1.yml
  |  | |> my_external_table_2.yml
  |  |
  |  |_ transforms
  |  |_ final
  |_ dbt_project.yml
  |_ readme.md
```

Where "my_external_table_1.yml" looks like:

```
sources:
  - name: external_db_schema
    database: my-bq-project-id
  
    tables:
      - name: my_external_table_1
        description: "Lorem Ipsum"
```

And your static view is defined by running a query like:

```
create view if not exists `my-bq-project-id.external_db_schema.my_external_table_1` as 
( SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("gcp-name.europe-west3.friendly_name",
  "SELECT * FROM database_name.external_table;"))
```

---

Example of #2

Just make a base level dbt model that does exactly what you are describing on a  1-1 object mapping:

`my_external_table_1.sql`

```
execute immediate (
  SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("gcp-name.europe-west3.friendly_name",
  "SELECT * FROM database_name.external_table;")
)
```

And then from here you'll be able to `ref('my_external_table_1')` in your transform layer etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As far as I understand solution 1, I would have to run the query to create the static view every time something changes in `my_external_table_1`, right? This is unfortunately not what I need. I guess I'll go with your solution 2 for now, even though its not ideal for documentation. One question - why do you use `execute immediate ()`? I cannot do that in my DBT and wondered about it's functionality.

Comment: I used `execute immediate ()` because I wasn't sure how well the quoted select statement within the `EXTERNAL_QUERY()` function call would perform given dbt. I've experimented a bit with passing select statements as strings before and the only solution was within an `execute immediate ()` function call.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean that "you cannot do that in your DBT" ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm newish to DBT & SQL still. So when trying to run a model with `execute immediate ()`, DBT gives me this error: "Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got keyword EXECUTE at [6:6]". So to me it looks like DBT doesn't know that command.

Comment: @andreas030241 were you able to resolve it.